# Trying to parse bbcode out of a string and I'm running into trouble when I have nested tags

Tags: javascript, regex

This

```
[b]this text is bold[/b]
[i]this text is [b]italic[/b][/i]
```

parse out to this (in html)

```
<b>this text is bold[/b]<br><i>this text is [b]italic</i></b>
```

**this text is bold[/b]
*this text is [b]italic***

using this function

```
function bbcode(input){
return input
.replace(/\[b\]([^]*)\[\/b\]/ig, '<b>$1</b>')
.replace(/\[i\]([^]*)\[\/i\]/ig, '<i>$1</i>');
}
```

I figure there has to be a problem with the regular expression finding each set of tags, but it appears that only the first bold tag and the last bold end tag are being parsed. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Nested logic in regex is hard, specially in JS since it doesn't support recursion.

Comment: What are you expecting `[^]*` to capture? Unless I'm mistaken, it's exclusion is applying to nothing, so it's essentially the same as `.*`.  You'll most likely want to make that clause non-greedy, by adding a `?` to make it `[^]*?`.  Or, you may wish to actually exclude characters.

Comment: Why not just replace `[b]` with `<b>`, `[/b]` with `</b>` and so on? Also, `[^]` has to be the most creative way to write `.` I've ever seen.

Comment: @Patashu Replacing each individual start/end will cause issues in the (rare) case that someone writes a start without an end, or vice versa.

Comment: I came to `[^]` as I was working off examples and regex syntax is difficult to get a hold of. Once I got something that worked I stopped fussing with it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s2hnN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function bbcode(input){
    var b = /\[b\]([^[]*(?:\[(?!b\]|\/b\])[^[]*)*)\[\/b\]/ig;
    var i = /\[i\]([^[]*(?:\[(?!i\]|\/i\])[^[]*)*)\[\/i\]/ig;
    while (input.search(b) !== -1) {
        input = input.replace(b,'<b>$1</b>');
    }
    while (input.search(i) !== -1) {
        input = input.replace(i,'<i>$1</i>');
    }
    return input.replace(/\n/ig, '<br>');
}
```

BBCode:

```
[b]x[b]y[/b]z[/b]
[b]this text is bold[/b]
[i]this text is [b]italic[/b][/i]
```

Usage:

```
var string = '[b]x[b]y[/b]z[/b]\n[b]this text is bold[/b]\n[i]this text is [b]italic[/b][/i]';
console.log(bbcode(string));
```

Output:

```
<b>x<b>y</b>z</b><br><b>this text is bold</b><br><i>this text is <b>italic</b></i>
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3TsDA/1/).

Comment: Does this work correctly if you have something like `[b]x[b]y[/b]z[/b]` with nested tags of the same type?

Comment: @Patashu It does not, but I believe that level of parsing goes beyond the scope of the question, so I'll be giving this answer my vote.

Comment: It is important to note that this will only work for limited number of nesting levels.